# Convert Columns into rows using pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I have the following table 'total_points'

```
YEAR | COUNTRY | POINTS
----------------------
2014 | UK      | 100
2014 | ITALY   | 200
2015 | UK      | 100
2015 | ITALY   | 100
2016 | UK      | 300
2016 | ITALY   | 300
```

Which I am trying to convert to the following using pivot tables

```
YEAR | UK | ITALY
----------------
2014 | 100 | 200 
2015 | 100 | 100
2016 | 300 | 300
```

My code is the following and I get a syntax error new 'pivot'. Any idea where I am making the mistake?

```
CREATE VIEW total_club_points_pivoted AS
select * 
from 
(
    select YEAR, COUNTRY, POINTS
    from total_points
) src
pivot
(
    POINTS
    for COUNTRY in (['UK'], ['ITALY'])
) piv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `'`:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select YEAR, COUNTRY, POINTS
    from total_points
) src
pivot
(
    MAX(POINTS) for COUNTRY in ([UK], [ITALY])  -- here removed ' + added agg func
) piv;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd698062bfb6e70642f27e0e3b5881a6)**

---

**EDIT:**

SQLite equivalent:

```
SELECT year,
     MAX(CASE WHEN Country='UK' THEN Points END) AS "UK",
     MAX(CASE WHEN Country='ITALY' THEN Points END) AS "Italy"
FROM total_points
GROUP BY year;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=8f1f8fcabe8a0303df21e6adbc7f8711)**

Answer (score 2):

You may use `case..when` structure with aggregate function `sum` :

```
CREATE VIEW total_club_points_pivoted AS
select YEAR, 
      sum(case when country = 'UK' then
         points
       end) as "UK",
      sum(case when country = 'ITALY' then
         points
       end) as "ITALY"       
  from total_points
 group by YEAR 
 order by YEAR;

 YEAR   UK  ITALY
 2014   100  200
 2015   100  100
 2016   300  300
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b27c4/4)

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes

```
CREATE VIEW total_club_points_pivoted AS
select * 
from 
(
    select YEAR, COUNTRY, POINTS
    from total_points
) src
pivot
(
    Sum(POINTS)
    for COUNTRY in (UK, ITALY)
) piv
```

Comment: Please format code as code and not as normal text (I will edit your answer accordingly).